# Github não esta registrando contributions

Tags: github

Estou com o seguinte problema com o Github, ele não esta registrando minhas contributions apesar de que no repositório mostra que as atualizações estão sendo realizadas sem nenhum problema.Alguem sabe o que pode ser?Atualmente estou usando o visual code.

[image: Não esta fazendo registro]

[image: Registro do repositório]

Comment: Você está realizando esses commits em um branche, ou no repositório master?

Comment: No repositório master.

Comment: Só para confirmar, posta seu github aí. 
Porém acredito que possam haver duas possibilidades, seu repositório é privado e você não ativou a opção 'Include private contributions on my profile', nas configurações da sua conta do GitHub.
Ou o e-mail que você está utilizando para commitar não está associado a sua conta do GitHub.

Comment: Meu Git  //github.com/Richar2

Comment: Mas o estranho e que um repositório que estava fazendo os registros normalmente também parou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rode esse comando no terminal `git config --global user.name` e veja se está aparecendo 'Richard' ou 'Richar2', se aparecer 'Richard', rode o seguinte comando `git config --global user.name "Richar2"` e depois tente commitar algo novamente, e veja se está contabilizando suas contribuições.

O motivo disso é que os seus últimos commits vieram com o nome de usuário `Richard`, porém seu nome no GitHub está como `Richar2`, e quando os mesmos estão diferentes, os commits realizados não são considerados seus.

Caso isso não resolva seu problema, também confira seu email `git config --global user.email` e veja se o e-mail configurado é o mesmo que você tem vinculado a sua conta do github, caso não for, rode o seguinte comando `git config --global user.email seuemailaqui`. (Mas acredito que o e-mail já está correto)

Comment: Valeu mesmo Marcelolx ! O problema era no nome mesmo.

Comment: Show de bola! :)